# git branch change history

Tags: git, branch, workflow

I want to keep the history of the new feature in git.

The idea is  modify the master branch only by merge request and that each branch has the name of the feature.

Is this ok? Or should each commit have a reference to the feature?

My question arose because several branches can work on the same file and when mixing in master, commits can be mixed from what I understand.
On the other hand you can also remove the branches.
so, after merge the feature_ branches in master and removing them, how do I know which commit (changes) corresponds to which feature?

In other words, If I carry the features in branches, how do I see the history that adds a feature of a removed branch?
if the commits of two branches are merged on the master. How do I know which branch each commit belongs to?

Comment: When a feature branch go, merged commits stay. They're the history.

Comment: It's not useful to keep references to a branch in each commit. Branches move around a lot.

Comment: if the commits of two branches are merged on the master. How do I know which branch each commit belongs to?

Comment: A commit doesn't "belong" to a branch. A branch is only a pointer to a single commit, a temporary label.

Comment: ok, I express myself in another way. After merge the feature_ branches in master and removing them, how do I know which commit (changes) corresponds to which feature?

Answer (score 2):

> How do I know which branch each commit belongs to?

This question has no answer, because in git (unlike some other version control systems) individual commits do not "belong" to a branch. Branches in git are fundamentally temporary and movable pointers to commits, used while developing to keep track of different streams of work, merge them together, etc.

The history in git consists entirely of the commits themselves. This includes the commit *messages*, which is why writing good commit messages is so important. Let's rephrase your question:

> How do I know which feature each commit was created as part of?

Note that this is a subtly different question: you are no longer asking about the *mechanics* of *how* the commit was created, but about the *reason why* the commit was created. That is something that a good commit message can tell you, in two ways:

- A well-written commit message will explain the reason for a change without the need for lots of external context.
- A standardised format for commit messages can help you see groups of commits in the log, for instance by including a project name or task number at the beginning of each message.

Comment: So to know which feature each commit is related to, am I required to reference the feature in each commit? This is not clear from the workflows that I have read from git https://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model It implies that using branches and merge request is enough, but I did not understand how to do it ... because from what you say it is not possible to do it

Comment: @user60108 Looking at that article, I see it does say that using merge commits lets you see how commits are grouped into features. That's true, because you can get the kind of diagram it shows there from a real repository (using `git log --graph`, or most GUI tools; but not, oddly, Github). What you _can't_ generally do is give that "bubble" in the commit graph a _name_ - you could leave a branch pointing at one of the commits, but you'd then have a very long list of branches in your repo. Treating the commit messages as the main source of "why" is much more reliable.

Comment: I'm playing with bitbucket and even if I delete the branch in merge request tab, I see a history of the changes associated with the feature. That is useful, but it's a big fault that you can't see which feature the commit is associated with.

Comment: @user60108 The concept of a "feature" exists only in your workflow, and the way you conceptualise your project. There is no field called "feature name" in git; there are branch names, which are intended to be cheap and mostly temporary; and there are commit messages, which are immutable.

Comment: I understand that, I was on the assumption of using feature by branches,  it is the git worflow that appears most suggested on the internet

Comment: @user60108 Most discussions of workflows are concentrating on how changes go _into_ releases - how you can effectively review and test them before they go live. The question of how to look at the code _afterwards_ is generally a secondary concern. In some version control systems, branches would be part of the answer to both problems; in git, branches are optimised to solve the _first_ problem. That's why some workflows recommend "fast-forward merges", or "squashed commits" - the branch was just a temporary means to an end, and gets thrown away when it's merged.